# Handling signals in multithreaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

I'm writing a multithreaded program as a project for a course, I wrote everything, I just needed to ask someone about some things that I'm not sure I'm doing right. The program, manages a hash table, and it is made by a server in python, 2 clients in C and a main program (still in C). The server communicates with the clients via socket, they read from files, and send the lines of text to the server, that using pipes sends them to the main program, that tokenizes them and inserts them in the hash table, or reads their value if present.

Now the project specifies that all signals must be handled, by a specific thread and in particular:

- when it is received SIGINT it must print the count of the elements in the hash table
- when it is received SIGUSR1 it must deallocate the hash table and create a new one
- when it is received SIGTERM it must wait for all the other thread to join (deallocate the memory) and terminate the program.

I handled this, masking all signals in the main, and reabilitating them when starting the signal handler, then it calls sigwait() inside a while loop, and it handles the signals like so:

```
while(1){
        sigwait(&mask,&signum);
        if(signum==SIGTERM){
            logging_log(arg->log,"INFO","[HANDLER] received SIGTERM");
            xpthread_join(*arg->capolet,NULL,here);
            xpthread_join(*arg->caposc,NULL,here);
            fprintf(stdout,"Elements in Hash_Table:%d\n",*(arg->Hash_elem));
            list_destroy(*arg->list);
            hdestroy();
            logging_log(arg->log,"INFO","[HANDLER] exiting");
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        if(signum == SIGINT){
            // logging_log(arg->log,"INFO","[HANDLER] received SIGINT");
            fprintf(stderr,"Elementi nella tabella: %d\n",*(arg->Hash_elem));
        }
        if(signum==SIGUSR1){
            write_lock(arg->hash_control);
                // logging_log(arg->log,"INFO","[HANDLER] received SIGUSR1");
                list_destroy(*arg->list);
                *arg->list = NULL;
                *(arg->Hash_elem)=0;
                hdestroy();
                xhcreate(Num_elem,here);
            write_unlock(arg->hash_control);
        }
    }
```

Now mind that all functions with an x before the name (like "xpthread_join()"), are just library function that handles errors, and I use a linked list to keep counts of all memory chunks that I allocate when inserting in the Hash table. Also "logging_log" is a functions that write (using a mutex) to a log file, define in the struct (arg->log).

Here are my questions:

1. Is it a problem that there's a small window of time, where all signals are masked in all the program (from when the main masks them, till the signal handler unmasks them)? Can i do something better?
2. Would it be better, to use specialized handlers (with sigaction) to, for example, handle the print of the value.
3. Since the program is multithreaded I created a struct "Hash_control" shared between threads that read or write in the hash table, and I made some functions to handle the "reader - writer problem" is, it good that when receiving SIGUSR1 the signal handler, has to contend the access to the hash table with the other threads? (I suppose it's not)

It would be fantastic, if someone told me what I'm doing wrong and what I can make better, but please note that I have to respect the specifics on top.

Thank You

Comment: Be aware that the term "signal handler" has a conventional meaning that is inconsistent with the way you are using it.  I was somewhat confused until I figured out that you were talking (I think) about a thread dedicated to synchronously handling signals.

Comment: What do you mean, when you say inconsistent?

Comment: By "inconsistent" I mean that when I say "signal handler" I mean something different (an asynchronous signal handling function) than you seem to do (a synchronous signal handling thread).

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: *when starting the signal handler*  Exactly how do you start your signal handler.  The "signal handler" phrase has specific meaning - a "signal handler" is a function called when a signal is received and it's installed/configured using `signal()` or `sigaction()`.  If you're starting a separate thread to call `sigwait()`, that's different.

Comment: @MattiaPiras Since you already deal with descriptors (sockets and pipes), probably you already have a kind of event loop. Consider to handle signals in the same event loop using `signalfd()` descriptor.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes I'm using a thread to handle signals, I'm not using sigaction, sorry for the misphrase

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it a problem that there's a small window of time, where all signals are masked in all the program (from when the main masks them,
>    till the signal handler unmasks them)? Can i do something better?

Not much of one.  If a signal arrives for the process while it is blocked by all threads, then it becomes pending for that process.  It will be delivered if and when it is unblocked.  HOWEVER, only one instance of each signal can be pending at a time, so if a flurry of signals arrives very close together then some may be lost.  And that could manifest even when signals are *not* blocked.

> 2. Would it be better, to use specialized handlers (with sigaction) to, for example, handle the print of the value.

Signal handlers such as you describe should run quickly, and they may call only async-signal-safe functions.  The `fprintf()` function is not async-signal-safe, though `write()` is.  I'm inclined to guess that some of the other functions you want to use there are not async-signal-safe either, so you're probably better off with synchronous signal handling such as you have implemented.

> 3. Since the program is multithreaded I created a struct "Hash_control" shared between threads that read or write in the hash
>    table, and I made some functions to handle the "reader - writer
>    problem" is, it good that when receiving SIGUSR1 the signal handler,
>    has to contend the access to the hash table with the other threads? (I
>    suppose it's not)

No, it isn't.  Even when you handle synchronously, you want your handling to be quick.  It's a fairly big problem if your handler thread may block for indefinite amounts of time.  One alternative would be for it to instead set a flag or enqueue an event or use some other, similar mechanism to indicate to other threads that the requested action should be performed when an opportunity to do so arrives.

That approach would also be a way to do your signal reception asynchronously, per (2).  If the handlers only register requests for action instead of performing the appropriate actions directly, then that would work around the issues I described above.

---

Note also that if you are indeed unblocking all the supported signals in the signal-handling thread, then you have a potential issue with one signal arriving while that thread is already handling another.  You might want to consider `sigsuspend()` instead of `sigwait()`, as the former allows you to unblock signals only temporarily, while you are waiting.  Do read its docs carefully however -- you will need to register signal-handling functions in this case, even if they do nothing at all.